# app bar in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, appbar

Greetings.

I was trying to add an app bar to the windows phone 8(VS 2013 & framework 4.5) application.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
        <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True" Mode="Default" Opacity="1.0" >

            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/save.png" Text="save" Click="Button1_Click" />
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/delete.png" Text="delete" Click="Button2_Click" />
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/help.png" Text="help" Click="Button3_Click" />
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/settings.png" Text="settings" Click="Button4_Click" />

            <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="get default size value" Click="MenuItem1_Click" />
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="get mini size value" Click="MenuItem2_Click" />
            </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>

        </shell:ApplicationBar>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

The app bar buttons are getting displayed in this specific page, but in other pages it is not visible. How we can make the app bar and its button visible **global**?

Thanking you in advance
Sebastian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you needed To create a global Application Bar that can be reused on multiple pages. Usually we create an Application Bar on the page we want to use it on, and it applies only to that page. For this purposes here is a good example [create a global Application Bar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394043%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) , you needed to create a global Application Bar by using XAML in App.xaml as shown in example.

`or`

You need to write same `AppBar` code in all individual pages for displaying it to all pages as you Described in Question

Comment: good resource link; How can I place the menu in a desired position(top left corner of page) ?

Comment: appbar's position is fixed by default as bottom of the page

Comment: can we use menu items without app bar?

Comment: Any reference url with some samples, would be helpful.

Comment: http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/How_to_use_Pop-Ups_in_Windows_Phone see this for popup and this for usercontrol http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/how-to-get-user-input-from-a-popup-in-windows-phone

Answer (score 0):

You can also create it programmatically and store a reference to it in your App.xaml.cs, and insert it in every page, in constructor, like this:

```
this.ApplicationBar = App.GlobalAppBar;
```

Creation is simple as:

```
ApplicationBarIconButton firstButton = new ApplicationBarIconButton();
firstButton.IconUri = new Uri("/Images/save.png", UriKind.Relative);
firstButton.Click += Button1_Click;
firstButton.Text = "save";
GlobalAppBar = new ApplicationBar();
GlobalAppBar.Buttons.Add(firstButton);
```